# AppSettingsPlugin.kt: Type mismatch: inferred type is Activity? but Activity was expected

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to make a release APK but always encounter this error

```
.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/app_settings-4.1.1/android/src/main/kotlin/com/example/appsettings/AppSettingsPlugin.kt: (44, 25): Type mismatch: inferred type is Activity? but Activity was expected

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app_settings:compileReleaseKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details
```

Below is the flutter doctor :

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on macOS 12.2.1 21D62 darwin-arm (Rosetta), locale ja-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2022.1.2)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2022.1.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.67.2)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```